# setup HTML div classes and setup div data attributes using jquery in Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a HTML code snippet like below

```
<div class="child-station-sub child-station-sub1">
<h4><a href='#' class="child-station-opener station1 open" data-staion="NORTH_SOUTH_LINE">North - South Line</a></h4>


<div class="child-station-sub child-station-sub2">
<h4><a href='#' class="child-station-opener station2 subdrop" data-staion="EAST_WEST_LINE">East - West Line</a></h4>


<div class="child-station-sub child-station-sub3">
<h4><a href='#' class="child-station-opener station3 subdrop" data-staion="COST_WEST_LINE">Cost - West Line</a></h4>
```

I'm trying to setup classes and html data attributes on when its loading

So I tried to do this using jQuery like following

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.listGroups)
{   

        <div id="divstation" class="child-station-sub child-station-sub1">
        <p class="hidden">@item.ID</p>
        <h4><a id="stationlg" href='#' class="child-station-opener station1 open" data-staion="EAST_WEST_LINE">@item.GroupName</a></h4>            

}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var idvalue = item.ID.ToString();

        if (idvalue == 1) {
            alert('sample')
            $('#divstation').attr('class', 'child-station-sub child-station-sub1');
            $('#stationlg').attr('class', 'child-station-opener station1 open');
            $('#stationlg').attr('data-staion', "NORTH_SOUTH_LINE");
        }

        else if (idvalue == 2) {
            $('#divstation').attr('class', 'child-station-sub child-station-sub2');
            $('#stationlg').attr('class', 'child-station-opener station2 subdrop');
            $('#stationlg').attr('data-staion', "EAST_WEST_LINE");
            });

        else if (idvalue == 3) {
            $('#divstation').attr('class', 'child-station-sub child-station-sub3');
            $('#stationlg').attr('class', 'child-station-opener station3 subdrop');
            $('#stationlg').attr('data-staion', "COST_WEST_LINE");
            });
</script>
```

but above attempt not working properly , what can I do here

Comment: You are creating elements in a loop, thus it will create duplicate IDs which will render invalid HTML __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__

Comment: this is not pure HTML , this is cshtml actually

Comment: @kelumpriyadarshane It will still create identical ids for multiple elements, which is a big no-no.

Comment: @Satpal in my C# method I'm loading those ID propely and sending to view , only concern is according to those varies IDs Load varies classes   ,

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't understand what you said, item.ID sending varies of IDs

Comment: @kelumpriyadarshane The loop at the top is creating multiple elements with the ids "divstation" and "stationlg". **Don't** do that. You **cannot** have the same id on more than one element.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to load a list with varies class , only need add classes on run time

Comment: @kelumpriyadarshane **But you're also loading multiple elements with the same ID. Just dont do that**.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so what can I do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.listGroups)
{
    string divClass;
    string aClass;
    string data;

    switch(item.ID.ToString())
    {
        case "1":
            divClass = "appropriate class for div";
            aClass = "appropriate class for a";
            data = "appropriate data attribute";
        break;

        /* other cases */
    }

    <div id="divstation_@item.ID" class="@divClass">
    <p class="hidden">@item.ID</p>
    <h4><a id="stationlg_@item.ID" href='#' class="@aClass" data-staion="@data">@item.GroupName</a></h4>
}
```

But it's really not the way it should be done. Instead you should consider using view model and passing all those data like necessary `class` and `data-*` values from backend, so you can simply render those items

```
foreach(var item in Model.Items)
{
    <div id="divstation_@item.Id" class="@item.DivStationClass">
        <p class="hidden">@item.Id</p>
        <h4><a id="stationlg_@item.Id" href="#" class="@item.AnchorClass" data-station="@item.DataStation">@item.GroupName</a></h4>
    </div>
}
```